# Hot Module Reload Not working in Laravel Vite

Tags: laravel, vite

This is my Code.

File.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title><?= Config::get('app.name') ?></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="<?= "fcontract-favicon.png" . '?v=' . Config::get('app.version') ?>">

    <!-- build:css(.) assets/css/vendor.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/PACE/themes/blue/pace-theme-minimal.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.min.css" />
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- lazyload Start -->
    <link id="lazyload-holder">
    <!-- lazyload End -->

    <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) assets/css/style.css -->
    <link href="vcontract/assets/styles/tabler.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vcontract/assets/styles/CssCustomize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vcontract/assets/styles/fa.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vcontract/assets/javascript/libs/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vcontract/assets/javascript/libs/alertify/css/alertify.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vcontract/assets/javascript/libs/alertify/css/default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vcontract/assets/javascript/libs/flatpickr/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <?php
    $viteAsset = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Vite::asset('resources/js/app.js');
    ?>
    <script type="module" src="<?= $viteAsset ?>"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" ng-class="{'border-top-wide border-primary d-flex flex-column':$state.includes('others.signin'), 'login-bg': themeConfig.isLoginBg}">
    <!-- Main view  -->
    <div id="app" ng-class="{'flex-fill d-flex flex-column justify-content-center py-4':$state.includes('others.signin')}">
        <h1>d</h1>
        <ui-view>
    </div>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/PACE/pace.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vcontract/assets/javascript/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vcontract/assets/javascript/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ui-jq/jq.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/perfect-scrollbar/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-deep-blur/angular-deep-blur.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vcontract/assets/javascript/libs/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
    <script src="vcontract/assets/javascript/libs/alertify/alertify.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vcontract/assets/javascript/libs/flatpickr/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vcontract/assets/javascript/libs/flatpickr/ng-flatpickr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vcontract/assets/lib/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/signaturepad/signature_pad.js"></script>

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/app.min.js -->
    <!-- Angular App Script -->

    <script src="<?php $path = "vcontract/scripts/utils.js";  echo $path . '?v=' . Config::get('app.version'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php $path = "vcontract/scripts/notificationService.js";  echo $path . '?v=' . Config::get('app.version'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php $path = "vcontract/scripts/app.js";  echo $path . '?v=' . Config::get('app.version'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php $path = "vcontract/scripts/app.ctrl.js";  echo $path . '?v=' . Config::get('app.version'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php $path = "vcontract/scripts/router.config.js";  echo $path . '?v=' . Config::get('app.version'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php $path = "vcontract/scripts/services/authService.js";  echo $path . '?v=' . Config::get('app.version'); ?>"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <script>
        angular.module("app").constant('CSRF_TOKEN', '<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>');
        var version_file = "<?= Config::get('app.version') ?>";
        var footerUrl = "<?= Config::get('app.footerUrl') ?>";
    </script>
</body>
```

And This is Vite.config.

```
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin'
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
plugins: [
    laravel({
            input: [
                // 'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
        output: 'public/dist',
        refresh: true,
    }),
],
server: {
    host: 'localhost',
    watch: {
        usePolling: true,
    },
},
resolve: {
    alias:{
        "@": "/resources"
    }
}});
```

Now I have another problem. Everytime I change something in my code, the updates are not show in my browser. Also not, if i reload the page. I have to exit the 'npm run dev' process and start the process again. Is my setting with server correct? And what else do I have to do? Have anybody an idea? Thanks

Comment: Why do you have literal PHP and a PHP file instead of `file.blade.php`? How are you loading it? It has to be a blade file, first of all...

Comment: Remember to always check/read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade) as you are no magician